# UnauthorizedAccessException from PowerShell when using Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: windows, powershell

I know that the error is pretty much self-explenatory but yet I am not able to find solution. I write a `PowerShell` script to automate the set-up project for the dev machines. There are a set of programs that must be installed so what I want to do i first download the file and then install it. I am having problems with downloading file from the web to the local machine.

My logic is as follows. I have an `.xml` file where I configure all the stuff. For the downloads it looks like this:

```
<download source="https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.5-preview20150319/Git-1.9.5-preview20150319.exe"
destination="C:\Temp" filename="Git-1.9.5-preview20150319.exe"/>
```

Then in my `PowerShell` script file I have this function:

```
function install-tools() {
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$xmlFileInformation = $config.SelectNodes("/setup/downloads/download");
Foreach ($file in $xmlFileInformation)
{
$("Filename: " + $file.filename)
$("File source: " + $file.source)
$("File destionation: " + $file.destination)

    $("****************************************************************");
    $("*** Downlading "+ $file.filename);
    $("****************************************************************");
    Invoke-WebRequest $file.source -OutFile $file.destination

}

$("Task finished");
}
```

After executin I get the error from the title `UnauthorizedAccessException from PowerShell when using Invoke-WebRequest`. Two things that I can mention is that I have included `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and also, I execute the script running `PowerShell` as administrator. I've tried different paths but it's the same everytime, I don't get permission to write anywhere. The only thing that I can't try is using another drive I have only one - `C:\`.

And one strange thing - my destination directory is `C:\Temp` but during one of my attempts I didn't have such a directory in `C:\` so I ended up with file named `Temp` in my `C:\` but this was the closest I get to getting a file.

I don't need to save those files in a particular place since it's very possible to delete the entire directory after successfull set-up so what I need is a way to let powershell save files somewhere in my `C:\` drive. Since I'm not sure if this is related with administrating my system and setting the correct rights (I tried to lower the protection as much as I can) or I miss something in my `PowerShell` script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You does not specify file name to download to. Replace

```
-OutFile $file.destination
```

to

```
-OutFile (Join-Path $file.destination $file.filename)
```